# Java 8 allocating too much memory

Tags: java, eclipse, memory-management, java-8

I am running `Eclipse 4.3` with a `Java 7 JRE`. When I upgrade to a `Java 8 JRE`, Eclipse suddenly consumes more memory. If I launch Eclipse with `JRE 7` directly into my workspace, it allocates 600 MB of RAM according to Task Manager. When I use `JRE 8`, this value is 750 MB.

Even worse, If I run a large Java program which typically allocates about 10 GB of RAM with `JRE 7`, switching to `JRE 8` causes it to allocate 12 GB of RAM.

Does anybody know what causes this extra RAM allocation? I have tested tweaking different options but with zero success:

```
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=
-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=
-XX:MetaspaceSize=
...
```

Comment: which number in the task manager are you looking at?

Comment: Why do think messing around with these very special options `ReservedCodeCacheSize`, `MaxMetaspaceSize` or `MetaspaceSize` is the way to go? Have you checked that these special memory areas are the cause of the higher memory consumption rather than the *ordinary heap size* first? Besides that, what’s the point of Eclipse consuming 750 MB instead of 600 MB? I’d be happy if Eclipse was ever that frugal on my machine…

Comment: indeed, my eclipse usually hovers around 2 GB RAM usage (i need to increase the default value sometimes) and java applications which use TEN GIGABYTES are most assuredly faulty by design; you shouldn't use such an app. There is no such thing like a "large Java program", if you manage to get your JAR-size noticeably higher than a few hundred MB you already are building massive application frameworks - Java is really efficient in terms of file-size, you wont ever reach the gigabyte-barrier unless you're doing it wrong.

Comment: I recall changes to the memory model around perm gen and mapped JARs. Might be an accounting difference, nothing more.

Comment: Might be related https://dzone.com/articles/java-8-permgen-metaspace. "This means you may observe an increase of the Java heap space".

Comment: @specializt your second point is misleading - you can have a small application (jar) that uses a lot of memory...

Comment: Did you try working with compressed pointers? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/vm/performance-enhancements-7.html#compressedOop

Comment: @Simon: In Java 8, compressed pointers are on by default.

Comment: I don't think it's PermGen. I checked PermGen in Java 7 and Metaspace in Java 8 and it is always below 200 MB. There are scientific applications which utilize a lot of memory and which are partially or fully written in Java.

Comment: Are you using 32 or is it 64 bit java?

Comment: Have you tried setting a default value for heap size? I am speaking for -Xmx and -Xms.

Comment: Does it matter? As of July Java 7 is [eol](https://www.java.com/en/download/faq/java_7.xml) and out of public updates.

Comment: Have you tried taking a heap dump and run it through [MAT](https://eclipse.org/mat/) to see the differences? If not, please do.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28363109/higher-memory-consumption-in-java-8-than-java-7

Comment: I use 64-bit Java - both Java 1.7 and Java 1.8. Both when compiling and when running the application. I have default values for heap size and metaspace size.

Answer (score 11):

In the way question is asked

> why Java 8 allocating too much memory on my machine

I don't think anyone will be able to answer, however there are several guidelines which might help. Given that you are measuring memory via task manager you are interested in total RSS used. So

- **Step 1:**
  Compare JVM defaults between version you are running. You can get them using `java -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version` command for both jdks. Using text sort on top of output you'll be able to get a nice diff using any compare tool. Things like changing default GC collector and thread stack size will affect final RSS a lot.
- **Step 2:**
  Measure allocation for each memory pool. In general total memory used by java could be calculated using `heap + metasize + code cache + native + (thread_stack_size * maximum_number_of_threads)`

  - Heap memory easy measurable (and could be easy compared!!) by mature tools ([Eclipse Memory Analyzer](https://eclipse.org/mat/), [VisualVM](https://visualvm.java.net/), etc.). If you memory
    increase in heap area -you are very lucky. In additional visual vm allow you to install plugin which will show values of all memory pools accessible via jmx.
  - metasize (aka permgen in jdk<8) should more/less equal and could be found with [`jmap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/jmap.html) tool. No need to play with flag, you can get number and just compare whenever it's increased or not.
  - [Code cache](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/embedded/develop-apps-platforms/codecache.htm): in addition to reserved code cache there you can set initial code cache (and that will affect how much RSS is used).
  - native: it's a bit of black sheep. If all other memory pools are equal (your memory bump is 2GB) memory lost must be somewhere in native area. The only tool I'm aware of is [`jcmd`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/nmt-8.html) and it has extensive documentation in oracle docs.

Non technical - whilst tweaking various options in order to reduce memory can help, the chances of getting right values are close to finding needle in haystack. I would really recommend to have a about how RSS is used in java. This knowledge will be handy for quite a few years!

Please let me know whenever you'd like more concrete references or better explanation. And... good luck with your quest ;-)

Comment: I don't see an increase in heap memory and metaspace memory when comparing JDK7 and JDK8 I did the measurements with ´jvisualvm´. Setting ReservedCodeCacheSize back to 48 MB as is the default value in JRE7 has only a minimal impact. It is the native memory that grows in size.

Comment: Are both jdks 64 (or 32) bits? Asking because you didn't specify that in question.

Comment: Yes, I use 64-bit only: 64-bit JDK7, 64-bit JDK8, 64-bit JRE7 and 64-bit JRE8.

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that a Web application I am working on (Jetty, Struts2, JDBC) consumes about 300 MBs more RAM (1.2G) right after startup when running in JRE 1.8.0_72 compared to JRE 1.7.0_80. The application is running on Centos 6 x64 and to make the memory measurement as transparent as possible I have disabled swap and set -Xms equal to -Xmx (40% of available RAM). I have used `dstat --top-mem` or `top -m` to get the total memory consumed by the java process.

Moreover when Web clients are connecting too often to the application, the total consumed memory rises until the system gets out of memory and kills the java process. The only what I can see is an information in /var/log/messages:

> Nov 10 21:29:54 my kernel: Out of memory: Kill process 26610 (java) score 570 or sacrifice child

When I run an infinite loop from bash that invokes 4 parallel Web clients that connect to the application (= establish new TCP connection), request the application status and disconnect then the total memory consumed by the application rises about 100-200 KBs each minute. Each client does 6-10 requests per minute.
Used heap memory size is stable.